# How to remotely build and run applications?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Idea 13 for developing software on windows(on java programming language).
I have also a macbook pro so I wonder if there is a way to code on the Macbook Pro (because I like the retina screen) and build and run all the code on the windows machine.
I am an experienced user so I am familiar with maven and I use it frequently to deploy the application(I have also created a nexus local repository).
I can't run all the code on mac because some critical parts of the application are running only on windows.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried remote desktop (something like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/pt/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417) )?

Comment: You can set up a Continuous Integration server on your Windows machine. Whenever you check in code in your VCS it can trigger a build on your CI server. Example of a Continuous Integration software is [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). There are plenty of others as well.

Comment: Yes, just use a VCS (Git, SVN...) to commit your code, whether your work on MacOS or Windows, then run the code on the Windows working copy.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Team City on your windows PC, and configure it to build your software whenever you commit to subversion. Running it may be more difficult though -- unless you're building a web-app, in which case you can have team-city run a maven command or script to deploy it to a container (such as tomcat).

[Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is free, from JetBrains.